# serverside fetch request timeout when request are to an external domain which has the same IP as origin domain

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, docker, ip

I'm currently running a SvelteKit app within a container which connects to an API running within aother container. Everything is connecting & going through locally using the container's `internal` URL. It also works without issue if I point the local app container to the staging server API container using the `external` URL. The issue arises when the containers run on the same staging server (same IP) using different staging subdomain URLs. Both containers are accessible from the outside as I can connect to both individually. However, there seems to be a problem with the fetch requests within the app container to the API container, which fail to connect to the API with a `UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT` error. If I use the `internal` URL from within the app container to point to the API container, it connects.

```
# Local Machine
# Local -> Internal | works
SvelteKit container    API container
localhost:5173      -> http://api:4000/api

# Local -> External | works
SvelteKit container    API container
localhost:5173      -> https://example.com/api

# Local & 3rd-party Server
$ wget --spider https://example.com/api
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2023-09-30 13:22:40--  https://example.com/api
Resolving example.com (example.com)... x.x.x.x
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|x.x.x.x|:443... connected.



# Remote Server
# Remote -> Internal | works
SvelteKit container    API container
https://app.example.com -> http://api:4000/api

# Remote -> External | fails UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT
SvelteKit container       API container
https://app.example.com -> https://example.com/api

# Host & WithinContainer
$ wget --spider https://google.com
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2023-09-30 13:29:12--  https://google.com/
Resolving google.com (google.com)... 172.217.13.174, 2607:f8b0:4020:806::200e
Connecting to google.com (google.com)|172.217.13.174|:443... connected.

$ wget --spider https://example.com/api
Spider mode enabled. Check if remote file exists.
--2023-09-30 13:22:40--  https://example.com/api
Resolving example.com (example.com)... x.x.x.x
Connecting to example.com (example.com)|x.x.x.x|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
```

I'm unsure why I am able to connect from outside to the remote server & and from the remote server to another server but not from the remote server to itself. Is this an issue with the server itself, an issue with the iptables firewall, an issue with the router or a combination of issues?

It seems the remote server can't won't connect to itself.